# bash arobase to wrap a string

Tags: php, bash

I opened /usr/local/bin/pecl to understand how it worked, and it has this block condition that I have a doubt about:

```
  if test "/usr/local/bin/php" = '@'php_bin'@'; then
    PHP=php
  else
    PHP="/usr/local/bin/php"
  fi
```

I believe that the condition never matches since the string "/usr/local/bin/php" will never change,
but then why add arobases around php_bin, do arobase have a special meaning ?

Comment: It looks like this may be some kind of template variable that is filled in before the script is interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generated from a [template](https://github.com/pear/pear-core/blob/master/scripts/pecl.sh) by the PEAR installer.

PECL is best run by the PHP binary that was used when installing PEAR, so the initialiser script attempts to use an absolute path to execute PHP. The string you see is there to check for the case where the installer did not successfully replace the place holder `@php_bin@` with an actual path to the PHP binary, in which case it will fall back to invoking the executing shell's default binary for the `php` command.